# Is a non-degenerate finite-dimensional algebra unital?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional (not necessarily unital) associative algebra over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ (but I'm also interested in more general fields). Assume the multiplication on $A$ is non-degenerate, which means that $A= AA$ and if $a \in A$ satisfies $aA = 0$ or $Aa = 0$, then $a=0$. Is it true that $A$ is unital? If not, what is a counterexample?

---

Some easy observations:

- If $A$ is also simple, then it can be shown that the answer is positive. This follows for instance by the argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/181839).
- If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra (which is automatically non-degenerate), then a finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra is automatically unital.

Comment: There are examples I believe coming from finite semigroups.  I'll add an example when I get a chance.   I just need to make sure $aA\neq 0$ for the example I have in mind.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I'm looking forward to see your counterexample :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a four-dimensional counterexample over any field.

$A$ has basis $\{e,a,b,c\}$, with all products of basis elements zero except for
$$e^2=e,\quad ab=c,\quad ea=a,\quad ec=c,\quad be=b,\quad ce=c.$$

(This is a codimension one ideal in the path algebra of the quiver with two vertices, two arrows $a$ and $b$ in opposite directions between the two vertices, modulo the relation $ba=0$.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything checks out nicely.